# Connecting tables to shopping cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Connecting tables to shopping cart

I have three models and three database tables that I want to connect to one cart, I'm new in rails and have some problem to do this.
My initial idea was 
Create model called Service as a parent of models Adverts, Package_of_products, and Subscriptions. And then connect it to cart by Line_item 
Already know that I am doing something wrong 
Each time when trying add one of my services to Line_items I getting message

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in LineItemsController#create

Couldn't find Service without an ID

app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:44:in `create'
```

Already I have

```
def create
  @cart = current_cart
  service = Service.find(params[:service_id])
  @line_item = @cart.line_items.build(:service => service)

respond_to do |format|
  if @line_item.save
    format.html { redirect_to(@line_item.cart, :notice => 'Line item was successfully created.')   
end
```

I have 4 databas and models my Line_items

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :service
belongs_to :cart
end
```

Cart

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :services,
has_many :adverts, :through => :services
has_many :package_of_products, :through => :services
has_many :subscriptions,:through => :services
```

Advert

```
class Advert < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :service
end
```

Subscriptions

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :service
end
```

Package_of_products

```
class PackageOfProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :service
end
```

Answer (score 2):

ok, first the association name is `belongs_to` instead of `belong_to`, so please correct that misprint.

and then i think you need smth like this:

```
class Cart  < ActiveRecord ::Base
  has_many :line_items, :dependant => destroy
  has_many :ads, :through => :line_items
  has_many :products, :through => :line_items
  has_many :services, :through => :line_items
end
```

check the `has_many :through` association [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association)